# How to use BibTeX in thebibliography in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies

Assuming that I have the below posted `bibtex`, how can I use it in LaTeX in the bibliography section `\begin{thebibliography}{1}`

Please provide an example for that.

```
 @article{ungar1997strategies,
 title={Strategies for knowledge acquisition from cartographic maps by blind 
 and visually impaired adults},
 author={Ungar, Simon and Blades, Mark and Spencer, Christopher},
 journal={The Cartographic Journal},
 volume={34},
 number={2},
 pages={93--110},
 year={1997},
 publisher={Maney Publishing}
}
```

Comment: You don't. Once you have a bibliography database, you don't want to do stuff by hand.

Comment: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852) and [biblatex for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)

Comment: @Johannes_B should i create a folder for the .bib files..if ys how can i add that folder in latex

Comment: Please read the linked material first.

Comment: As it stands, my feeling here is to close (duplicate or off-topic) since as @Johannes_B says you need to read some general introductory material.