# How to reference JabRef generated .bib-file in LaTeX document?

Tags: biblatex, jabref

I am using JabRef to create the bibliography. I added all the entries, generated the required key for each entry and saved the entries in a file named `refs.bib`. I want to add the references/bibliography I created in my document, so I used the following commands:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
\end{thebibliography}
```

When I compile the code, I get empty pages despite `refs.bib` contains data.
Please let me know how to correctly use the JabRef file in LaTeX.

**Note**: the `refs.bib` file is located in the same directory of the LaTeX document

Comment: Do you have any `\cite` instructions in the main body of your tex file? If so, first delete the directives `\begin{thebibliography}{1}` and `\end{thebibliography}`. Second, run the compilation sequence latex-bibtex-latex-latex on your tex file. Assuming you have no errors in the bib file and the `\cite` instructions, this compilation sequence will generate the citation call-outs as well as the formatted bibliography itself. I've noticed you've set the `biblatex` tag: Is the biblatex package loaded in the preamble of the tex file?

Comment: You can use `\nocite{*}` to cite everything in your `.bib` file at once (nice for testing). Since bibtex generates a `\begin{thebibliohraphy}{...} .... \end{thebibliography}` structure in an external file, you basically have nested `thebibliography` environments, which does not make any sense.

Comment: @Mico I have deleted the \begin{thebibliography}{1} and \end{thebibliography} and now only the \bibliography{refs.bib} is there..but still i got empty page

Comment: Also exactly what are you using here? Your question is marked `biblatex`, and since you have not provided a full minimal example we cannot verify that you are actually using `biblatex`. If you are using `biblatex` then `\bibliography{refs.bib}` is not the recommended syntax (not use if `biblatex` even supports it. Please update your question to have a full minimal example so we can see the document class and preamble.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you seem to mix a lot of approaches to bibliographies here (manual `thebibliography`, traditional BibTeX, `biblatex`). Have a look at an introduction to bibliographies in LaTeX (e.g. http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/citations.html, https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX). Note, however, that `\bibliography{refs.bib}` is always wrong, the command `\bibliography` expects the file name without extension: `\bibliography{refs}` would be correct.

Comment: I just notes you asked a question before (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285541/35864) and it was suggested you should read some introductory material there. [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) is another good start.

Comment: Any news here? Currently your question is not clear at all and thus not really answerable.